# Change button text automatically when screen is resized with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

Consider this codes:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn-block">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New Item</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    button {
        content: '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>';
    }
}
```

If you resize the screen horizontally, at some moment the text will get out of the button.

I want to know if is possible to change the button text automatically when the horizontal screen resizes. Something like "+ Add New Item" to only the plus signal "+" in small devices.

I'm a little noob with media queries, so I think I'm missing something or doing it wrong.

Can someone help me?

I made this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ogt84jds/) for it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xo9xkv05/1/).

Add a class to the button text, set `display:none` when the screen size is small enough:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn-block">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    <span class="button-text">Add New Item</span>
</button>
```

And CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .button-text {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Suggestion: never put DOM structure or information inside CSS styles. It is hard to maintain.

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm for me, with a minimal code modification. Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

You could do this without adding any additional media queries or CSS by using the built in responsive utilities within Bootstrap:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn-block">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">Add New Item</span></button>
</div>
```

It adds a bit more HTML markup, but the extra data is either going in the HTML, or in the CSS, so whichever works best for you.

Comment: Nice solution too! But in my case I need extra CSS because I need to change the default bootstrap max-width value for sm/xs.

Comment: great answer..!

Comment: Since bootstrap 4 the classes for hiding / displaying have changed. Check out this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Answer (score 3):

If you use Bootstrap, then it's as simple as sneaking in two classes.

`hidden-sm` and `hidden-xs` **hide** the element when the screen width is medium or small, respectively.

So simply, you want  to be hidden when the screen is small, just apply those classes!

Example:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-person"></span>
    <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Profile</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just create another media query (at the point where you think the text should change), and hide the text within the button. Instead of placing the button where it is now, encapsulate it in a `<span>`, then write some CSS to set `display` to `none` once the page is becoming smaller than x pixels.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn-block">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span>Add New Item</span></button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: <change this value>) {
    button span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

---

However, I think this should be resolved with jQuery since there is no way to guarantee that this is going to work if you place the button at other places. You should try to see if the content of the button is wider than the button's width itself, then add a 'invisible' class accordingly

I modified your jsfiddle a bit, however, jQuery seems to be a bit buggy on this one (try printing the values I'm using in the function)

https://jsfiddle.net/ogt84jds/1/

Comment: Thanks for replying, I wanted a solution that did not need a jquery code.

Answer (score 1):

I made a fiddle showing and hiding 2 different buttons that is maybe not the best way, but hey, it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/xo9xkv05/

HTML

```
<div class="less">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn-block"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="more">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn-block"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New Item</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.less {
    display:none;
}
@media (max-width: 300px) {
    .less {
        display:block;
    }
    .more {
        display:none;
    }
}
```